# Aggregate a tibble based on a consecutive values in a boolean column

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I've got a fairly straight-forward problem, but I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't require a wall of code and complicated loops.

I've got a summary table, `df`, for an hourly timeseries dataset where each observations belongs to a group.
I want to merge some of those groups, based on a boolean column in the summary table.
The boolean column, `merge_with_next` indicates whether a given group should be merged with the next group (one row down).
The *merging* effectively occurs by updating the `end`, value and removing rows:

```
library(dplyr)

# Demo data
df <- tibble(
  group = 1:12,
  start = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-12 00:00"), by = "1 day"),
  end = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 23:59"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-12 23:59"), by = "1 day"), 
  merge_with_next = rep(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 4)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    group start               end                 merge_with_next
#>    <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>          
#>  1     1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  2     2 2019-01-02 00:00:00 2019-01-02 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  3     3 2019-01-03 00:00:00 2019-01-03 23:59:00 FALSE          
#>  4     4 2019-01-04 00:00:00 2019-01-04 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  5     5 2019-01-05 00:00:00 2019-01-05 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  6     6 2019-01-06 00:00:00 2019-01-06 23:59:00 FALSE          
#>  7     7 2019-01-07 00:00:00 2019-01-07 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  8     8 2019-01-08 00:00:00 2019-01-08 23:59:00 TRUE           
#>  9     9 2019-01-09 00:00:00 2019-01-09 23:59:00 FALSE          
#> 10    10 2019-01-10 00:00:00 2019-01-10 23:59:00 TRUE           
#> 11    11 2019-01-11 00:00:00 2019-01-11 23:59:00 TRUE           
#> 12    12 2019-01-12 00:00:00 2019-01-12 23:59:00 FALSE

# Desired result
desired <- tibble(
  group = c(1, 4, 7, 9),
  start = c("2019-01-01 00:00", "2019-01-04 00:00", "2019-01-07 00:00", "2019-01-10 00:00"),
  end = c("2019-01-03 23:59", "2019-01-06 23:59", "2019-01-09 23:59", "2019-01-12 23:59")
)

desired
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   group start            end             
#>   <dbl> <chr>            <chr>           
#> 1     1 2019-01-01 00:00 2019-01-03 23:59
#> 2     4 2019-01-04 00:00 2019-01-06 23:59
#> 3     7 2019-01-07 00:00 2019-01-09 23:59
#> 4     9 2019-01-10 00:00 2019-01-12 23:59
```

*Created on 2019-03-22 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)*

I'm looking for a short and clear solution that doesn't involve a myriad of helper tables and loops. The final value in the `group` column is not significant, I only care about the `start` and `end` columns from the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and create groups based on every time `TRUE` value occurs in `merge_with_next` column and select `first` value from `start` and `last` value from `end` column for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(temp = cumsum(!lag(merge_with_next, default = TRUE))) %>%
  summarise(group = first(group),
            start = first(start), 
            end = last(end)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp)

#  group start               end     
#  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1     1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-03 23:59:00
#2     4 2019-01-04 00:00:00 2019-01-06 23:59:00
#3     7 2019-01-07 00:00:00 2019-01-09 23:59:00
#4    10 2019-01-10 00:00:00 2019-01-12 23:59:00
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.